# Factory Pattern Database connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, design-patterns, factory

I am  trying to implement factory pattern on database connection using MySQL, SQL Server facing weird error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on SQL command object

```
internal class SqlServerDB : IDatabase
{
    private SqlConnection _Connection = null;
    private SqlCommand _Command = null;

    public IDbCommand Command
    {
            get
            {
                if (_Command == null)
                {
                    _Command.Connection = (SqlConnection)Connection;

                    //_Command = new SqlCommand();
                }
                return _Command;
            }
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
            get
            {
                if (_Connection == null)
                {
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testSQL"].ConnectionString;
                    _Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                }
                return _Connection;
            }
    }
}
```

Database factory section :

```
public static class DatabaseFactory
{
            public static IDatabase CreateDatabase(DBType type)
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case DBType.SqlServer:
                        return new SqlServerDB();

                    case DBType.MySql:
                        return new MySQLDB();
                }

                return null;
            }
}
```

Main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDatabase database;
    DBType databaseType = DBType.SqlServer;

    database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(databaseType);
    IDbConnection connection = database.Connection;

    IDbCommand command = database.Command;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "select * from User";

    connection.Open();
}
```

and the selection of database by Enum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is an error on the first if,

```
if (_Command == null)
{
    _Command.Connection = (SqlConnection)Connection;
    //_Command = new SqlCommand();
}
```

Could be more like:

```
if (_Command == null)
{
    _Command = new SqlCommand();
    _Command.Connection = (SqlConnection)Connection;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use your own switch statement.

First of all, make sure that your connectionString contains a providerName like this:

```
< ?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <connectionstrings>
        <add name="Name"  providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" connectionString="Valid Connection String;"></add>
    </connectionstrings>
</configuration>
```

then you can create your connection by using:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConName"];
var providerName = connectionString.ProviderName;
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
connection.Open();
```

*(Add null checks so that you can tell your user/developer that the configuration is wrong)*

that way you can support most SQL databases as long as you stick to common sql queries.

Want to know more about proper ADO.NET handling?
http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/