# mvn spring-boot: run with additional jar

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, maven, jar

I am trying to create universal app (Maven, Java, Spring Boot) which connects to a chosen database where properties for connection are provided in command line. Everything works OK, but I have a problem with the database driver. The app is universal, so we don't store drivers inside the app.

My first idea was to provide suitable database driver JAR somehow with mvn spring-boot:run command, but it doesn't work for me. I was trying different options.

Can anyone tell me how I can provide a database driver when I am starting app using mvn spring-boot:run?

Comment: Is it an app that communicates with a different version of the same database or it communicates with different flavors of databases? You can keep the jar in the CLASSPATH and add that at maven dependency as `provided`

Comment: it should be able to connect to different databases (e.g. postgresql, oracle, mysql) - it all depends what we provide in command line. we also can't handle dependencies for drivers inside the project / pom.xml

Comment: You can implement the factory design pattern and based on the input you can initialize the required drivers, check this question if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249064/factory-pattern-database-connection/44249171

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factory Pattern Database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249064/factory-pattern-database-connection)

Comment: I'm not sure... I still don't know how to provide jdbc driver by command line. I should provide the path to the driver and application should works (connect with  the suitable DB). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can provide the `type` as the command line parameter, ex., `java -jar <jar_file> type=Postgres` then based on the `type` use the factory pattern in the code.